# Filter a fileset referenced using a refid

Tags: ant, fileset

I have a fileset (which is returned from the Maven Ant task), and it contains all the jars I need to repack. This fileset is referenced by a refid. I only want to include our own jars, so I would like to filter that. But Ant filesets don't support any further attributes or nested tags if a refid is used.

For example, if the fileset is:

```
org.foo.1.jar
org.foo.2.jar
log4j.jar
```

and I want to have a fileset which contains only

```
org.foo*.jar
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try using a [`restrict`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#restrict) resource collection, which you can use like a `fileset` in any task  that uses resource collections to select the groups of files to operate on.

For example, for a `fileset` returned from your Maven task referenced via an id called `dependency.fileset` you can declare a `restrict` resource collection like so:

```
<restrict id="filtered.dependencies">
    <fileset refid="dependency.fileset"/>
    <rsel:name name="org.foo*.jar"/>
</restrict>
```

Note you'll have to declare the resource selector namespace as it isn't part of the built-in Ant namespace:

```
<project xmlns:rsel="antlib:org.apache.tools.ant.types.resources.selectors">
    ...
</project>
```

From here you can reference your `restrict` resource collection in a similar fashion to how you would reference your `fileset`. For example, to create backups of your filtered set of files:

```
<copy todir=".">
    <restrict refid="filtered.dependencies"/>
    <globmapper from="*" to="*.bak"/>
</copy>
```

Of course you can inline your `restrict` resource collection if you so desire:

```
<copy todir=".">
    <restrict>
        <fileset refid="dependency.fileset"/>
        <rsel:name name="org.foo*.jar"/>
    </restrict>
    <globmapper from="*" to="*.bak"/>
</copy>
```

Have a look at the Ant documentation on [resource collections](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#collection) for further information.

Comment: Good examples of using resources. I think the examples in the Ant docs could be improved, so this is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to write an ant task for that. They're pretty easy to write though.

See http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html#writingowntask

In your task, you'll need to call getProject() and ask it to give you the fileset, walk through it, and create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a sufficiently recent version of Ant and the JDK, for example, Ant 1.7 and JDK 6, then you can use the [optional script task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) to do what you want.  (Earlier versions may also work.)  The page I linked to, if you scroll down to the text "The goal is to list the filesizes" then you'll see a sample script that creates a Fileset.

This isn't for the faint of heart, and a custom ant task you write yourself will probably be more flexible.  But I wanted to point out the option.

Answer (score 1):

I 'm using Ant with [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/). With the help of Ivy it is possible to filter dependencies for retrieval, with the following code in ivy.xml:

```
<dependency name="Project1" rev="latest.integration" transitive="true" conf="modlibs">
<exclude name="${exclusionRegEx}" matcher="regexp" />
</dependency>
<dependency name="Project2" rev="latest.integration" transitive="false" conf="modules"/>
```

Maybe a quick look at the Ivy source 'll help?