# ANT create fileset from fileset

Tags: ant

I know this must be easy but I can't figure out how to do it. I have an existing fileset (from a 3rdparty task) . I'd like to now create a new fileset that includes everything from the first with a few excluded. I should be able to do

```
<fileset refid"origFileset">
<exclude name="foobar/>
</fileset>
```

For some reason ant is complaining about this basic operation.

Comment: missing `=` between `refid` and the quoted string

Comment: Can you give us why do you want to do this in that way? Maybe you are doing something wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ant filter fileset which is referenced by refid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607338/ant-filter-fileset-which-is-referenced-by-refid)